# Serialize in memory object with C#

Tags: c#, serialization, assemblies, in-memory

I've got a program that picks up some code from script files and compiles it.
And It works fine.

The problem is: in the scripts I declare a couple of classes and I want to serialize them.
Obviously the C# serializer (xml and binary) doesn't like to serialize and the de-serialize object defined in a in-memory assembly.

I prefer to don't leave the in-memory assembly so i'm looking for another way of serializing, but in case, is possible to build assembly in memory and eventually write it on file ?

Answer (score 1):

You could always write your own ToXml function using reflection to write out your property data to a string.  Then your object would deserialize itself.

Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create assemblies dynamically look into IL emitting via reflection.  [Here is a good article to get you started.](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/28783)

Answer (score 0):

So just to clarify, are you asking how you can serialize a type if it hasn't got the [Serializable] attribute applied?

One solution is to use the WCF Data Contract Serializer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923.aspx.

Obviously this will only work if you can target .Net 3.0 or higher.

Alternately you can implement an ISerializationSurrogate. Jeffrey Richter has a great introduction at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188950.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid all built-in serialization whenever possible, both are badly broken. For example, XML serialization doesn't support dictionaries and normal serialization/SOAP doesn't support generics. And both have versioning issues.

It is time consuming, but createing ToXML and FromXML methods is probably to most effective way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Hava a look [at here](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx) for custom serialisers, which is a sample for dictionary XML serializing

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly confused by the statement that the XmlSerializer can't serialize dynamically generated types. The XmlSerializer generates it's own serialization code dynamically as well during construction so there should be no issue with it serializing your type.

You may need to decorate your dynamic classes with the appropriate attributes, depending on what you are generating (like derived classes), but there shouldn't be any issue with using the XmlSerializer in the situation you described.

If you could post details about the issues the XmlSerializer is giving you I can help you work out what the problem is.

Also, I'm of the belief that auto-generating code is in general a blessing. All to often have I had to go back into a class to fix one or all of the copy/paste/save/load functions, just because someone forgot to update them when adding a new variable. Save/Load code is boiler plate code. Let the computers write it.